# SelectedItem in Win 8 Phone ListPicker is not shown

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, toolkit, selectedindex, listpicker

I use some `ListPicker` to manage my apps settings.
As I can see in when using a breakpoint in `OnNavigatedTo()`, the `SelectedIndex` is always set to the correct value, but when the dialog is shown, all `ListPicker` show the first item.

When I popup a `LictPicker`, then the correct item is highlighted and also saved correctly when the dialog is closed.

The Definition in XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ListPickHybrid" Margin="0,0, 0, 0" 
  SelectedIndex="{Binding HybridSetting, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource appSettings}}" BorderBrush="White" >
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Nur Online" />
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Immer offline" />
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Automatisch" />
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

And here is the code:

```
public int HybridSetting {
    get {
        int val = GetValueOrDefault<int>(BIS_Common.SETTINGS_HYBRIDMODUS, (int)HybridModus.Hybrid_Undefined);
         return val;
    }
    set {
        if (AddOrUpdateValue(BIS_Common.SETTINGS_HYBRIDMODUS, value)) {
            HybridModus status = (HybridModus) value;
            if (status != HybridModus.Hybrid_Undefined)
                BIS_Common.settingHybridStatus = status;
            Save();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I make some nonsens as:

```
try { ListPickHybrid.SelectedIndex = 99; }
catch (Exception) { }
```

In the `OnNavigatedTo()` the exception is thrown and then the `ListPicker` shows the correct Item !!

It makes no sense to me, that changing the `SelectedIndex` to an not existing value, brings me to the achieved goal.
What else can I do, to make `ListPicker` shows the selected item after starting up?

Comment: Hi Gibbsnich,
I know this is a very old thread, but did you find solution to your issue? I ran into the exact same issue just now. The selected item will not be selected in "normal" mode, but is selected in FullScreen mode

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same Issue right now... Just in case anybody runs needs it, I have found another crude workaround:

Before the ItemSource is populated:

```
this.YourPicker.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

After the ItemSource is populated:

```
this.YourPicker.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a crude workaruond but try using the "open()" method on the listpicker after it has been populated with items and the "SelectedItemIndex" has been set.

```
ListPickHybrid.open();
```